# EPPlus C# - Add Separators Between Duplicate Rows

Tags: c#, linq, epplus

I am transferring the data from the database to an excel document with EPPlus. I grouped the data from the database. No problem so far. I need to separate the grouped data with new row. I tried several methods myself but it doesn't work right. Because after the row is added, the row indexes are completely mixed. Can you help me?

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        
        using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr))
        {
            using (MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT ki.musteriAdi, kv.vardiya, ki.isTuru, ki.isAdi, ki.liman, ki.booking, ki.parti, SUM(konteynerAdet) FROM konteynervardiya AS kv, konteynerisi AS ki WHERE ki.ID=kv.konteynerIsiID GROUP BY kv.vardiya, ki.isAdi ORDER BY kv.vardiya, ki.liman", conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                da.Fill(dt);   
                conn.Close();
            }
        }

        List<String> vardiyalar = new List<String>();            

        using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr))
        {
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT kv.vardiya AS kvvardiya, SUM(kv.konteynerAdet) AS kvkonteyneradet FROM konteynervardiya AS kv, konteynerisi AS ki WHERE ki.ID=kv.konteynerIsiID GROUP BY kv.vardiya, ki.isAdi ORDER BY kv.vardiya, ki.liman",conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                using (MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {                        
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        vardiyalar.Add(dr["kvvardiya"].ToString());                           
                    }
                    conn.Close();
                }
            }               
        }    
      
        using (ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage())
        {
            var worksheet = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Attempts");
            worksheet = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Konteyner Çalışma Raporu");

            var cells = worksheet.Cells["A1:H1"];
            worksheet.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dt, true, OfficeOpenXml.Table.TableStyles.None);

            worksheet.TabColor = Color.Gold;
            worksheet.DefaultRowHeight = 12;
            worksheet.Row(1).Height = 18;
            worksheet.Row(1).Style.VerticalAlignment = OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelVerticalAlignment.Center;

            using (ExcelRange Rng = worksheet.Cells[1, 1, 1, 8])
            {
                Rng.Style.Font.Bold = true;
                Rng.Style.Font.Color.SetColor(Color.White);
                Rng.Style.Fill.PatternType = OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
                Rng.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.DeepSkyBlue);
            }

            worksheet.Cells[1, 1].Value = "MÜŞTERİ";
            worksheet.Cells[1, 2].Value = "TARİH/VARDİYA";
            worksheet.Cells[1, 3].Value = "YÜKLEME/TAHLİYE";
            worksheet.Cells[1, 4].Value = "İŞ İSMİ";
            worksheet.Cells[1, 5].Value = "LİMAN";
            worksheet.Cells[1, 6].Value = "BOOKING";
            worksheet.Cells[1, 7].Value = "PARTİ";
            worksheet.Cells[1, 8].Value = "YÜKLEME/LASHING";              
         

            var indices = from number in vardiyalar.Distinct()
                          select vardiyalar.ToList().LastIndexOf(number);
            int[] aIndices = indices.ToArray();
                           

            foreach (int iIndex in aIndices)
            {
                int index = iIndex +1;
                
                worksheet.InsertRow(index, 1, 1);                                     

            }

            worksheet.Cells.AutoFitColumns();
            worksheet.Cells.Style.HorizontalAlignment = OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelHorizontalAlignment.Center;

            pck.Workbook.Properties.Title = "Attempts";
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment;filename={0}", "Konteyner Çalışma Raporu.xlsx"));
            Response.BinaryWrite(pck.GetAsByteArray());
            Response.End();
        }
```

Normally each date and time group should be separated by a . However, there are errors as seen in the image.

[wrong table screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cIM5C.png)

[must have table screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSDCv.jpg)

Comment: Consider doing it like we do with any collection that we modify while skipping over it; loop it in reverse. When you operate in reverse, inserting a row at e.g. position 10 affects all the indexes after 10, but because you're going in reverse you already did those; your next row you operate on will be 9, which is not affected by inserts at position 10

Comment: @CaiusJard It really did. Thank you. The problem was solved when I reversed the array with the last indexes.